# This is an error i have been encountering for a while now "Module not found: Can't resolve '../lib'", no idea what the problem is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { FiAirplay } from "react-icons/all"; 
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer">
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

error: Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-icons/ai/index.esm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../lib'

please what am i doing wrong?,

Answer (score -1):

well your import statement is wrong..must be vs code autocomplete feature as i always get this.

```
import { FiAirplay } from "react-icons/fi";
```

Comment: "react-icons/all" contains every possible icon, so the import statement is right, look at the error again please